# bootstrap3 vertical align text inside column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know that this question has been asked several times but none of the solutions are worked for me i just want to center my text inside a column. Here is my mark up:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="#">Text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just wanted to vertically center the link text inside the column only using bootstrap classes if it is possible, if not I prefer not to use any constant `px` values.

Comment: The flexbox solution in the duplicate question seems to work: http://www.bootply.com/sUDK3Yv2GU

Comment: yeap this is what i am looking for. sorry i missed that. should i delete the question or leave it as is